# How to run 2 Gradle tasks in parallel in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio I can start successfully my application and reload changes with the "Restart Activity" button, but when my application is started, if I run a Gradle task (unrelated to the application but in the same project), then I cannot reload my changes anymore. The reload waits for the end of the Gradle task execution.

I tried with 2 Gradle tasks, the first one which waits for some time and the other which simply prints something. If I run the first one, then the second one, the second task is executed only when the first one is terminated.
I noticed that this does not happen IntelliJ IDEA, I can run the 2 tasks in parallel.

I tried to add the following parameters in my gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

but it does not change anything (except that Gradle Daemons are used).

Is this a known issue in Android Studio? Is there a way to disable it?